# Is there is any other data type larger than long long int that can be handled by GCC compiler?

Tags: c++

And I am not able to compile a programming because of the same. I have tried `long long int` to get the value of 11^26..

However while debugging I see the value changes abruptly when I reach 11^20 as in the last digit of the number instead of being one changes to another number.

Comment: Well, there _are_ data types that can store values much higher than 11^26...

Comment: Did you try `unsigned long long int` ?

Answer (score 2):

No. The biggest that is present now is (for positives) `uint64_t`.
You can use some library implementation (e.g. http://gmplib.org/) or implement your own type.

Comment: Hmm `uint64_t` actually is able to hold bigger values than `int64_t`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: You mean bigger positive values? That wouldn't be very surprising given its (un) signed-ness

Comment: @AndyG I meant the OP referred to `long long int`. So saying _no_ is actually wrong.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Ah yes, I see what you mean. Confusing indeed. I suppose if we get pedantic, the answer isn't technically wrong because OP is asking for data types larger than `long long int` which is just 8 bytes, and so is `uint64_t`.

Comment: I have tried unsigned long long int as well. Unsuccessful.. I need 26 digits.. Unsigned long long int give me only 20

Comment: I could, however, make an arbitrary `struct` holding a variety of `size_t`s which would exceed 8 bytes, so I suppose we also must also make some minor assumptions about what "data type" means in this context.

Comment: @AndyG Yes, the only nitpick I have is the _no_ and some reformulation related to what's asked in the question. `size_t` is equivalent to `uint64_t`  also IIRC.

Comment: @Shivam: Like the answers here suggest, you'll need to find a library that provides something akin to a BigInt class. Or roll your own. You can make a really basic one by just using a `std::vector`

Comment: Stressing on the fact - new to C++ as well .. So if you can pass on the code it would be pretty helpful

Comment: @Shivam _Gimme teh codez plz_ isn't well appreciated here, and becomes too broad. Do you strictly need an integer value for calculations, or would a `double` suffice?

Comment: I am sorry. New to stack overflow as well. Anyways. I need a a integer strictly. Because I have to get the last two digits of the number I get and work upon them..